# Is there a way to copy or create a folder in the Electron app package root directory?

Tags: electron, electron-forge

Upon packaging my Electron app using Electron Forge, I need to have a folder inside the package folder and
need to reference to that folder in my application:

Example:

Create a folder named "source" inside this directory:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Is this possible?

I found a way that would copy a folder in the resources folder using `"extraResource"` in forge's `"packagerConfig"` but I don't know how or if I can reference to that folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I could not find a way to create or copy a folder in the root directory of the package, so I just explored using `"extraResource"` in forge's `"packagerConfig"`. Apparently I can reference to that folder.

To make sure it works in both dev and production environments, just create the same structure in your app:

`${app_root}/resources/source` (I actually renamed 'source' but retained this to be clear)

And just reference it the usual way. Then in your package.json:

```
"config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {
        "name": "MyApp",
        "extraResource": "resources/source"
      }
...
```

Once you package your app (`npm run package`), you should see the "source" folder copied in the resources folder of your packaged electron app.

Marking this as the answer for now unless there really is a way.

Comment: https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/main/interfaces/electronpackager.options.html#extraresource

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here. My solution is to use one of their hooks in `forge.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {},
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    ...
  ],
  hooks: {
    packageAfterCopy: async (config, buildPath, electronVersion, platform, arch) => {
      var src = path.join(__dirname, '../your/path/');
      var dst = buildPath;
      fs.cpSync(src, dst, {recursive: true});
    }
  }
};
```

Note: you'll need the latest version of node.js to run `fs.cpSync`